# Can't run Lumen Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have really silly question. I am new at Lumen. I find out that in 5.2 and 5.3 there isn't a command `php artisan serve`. How can I run it using xampp?

Comment: XAMPP includes apache so you don't need to serve it via `artisan serve`. There's lots of resources online on how to run laravel in apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use php built in server in your project root in cli `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`